# Toggle view bettween 2 divs in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say that we have to `divs`.

```
<div class="first">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <p>goodnight</p>
</div>
```

What i want to do is to have a `button`to use it as a switch beetween those two divs.

When the document loads, i want only to see the first div and after the button is pressed to see only the second div, and goes on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, we were thinking the same thing :) I saw your comment after answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.second').hide();
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.first,.second').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <p>goodnight</p>
</div>

<button>switch</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggleClass()` to toggle the `hidden` class:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block first">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>

<div class="block second hidden">
  <p>goodnight</p>
</div>

<button id="btn">Toggle</button>
```